# /private assets crashes Meteor locally on Windows machine

Tags: meteor

I have been playing around on Windows 7 and tried to run my Meteor app locally with a 500 mb file in the `private` folder. It doesn't even boot up. Here's the sequence:

1. `meteor create test`
2. `cd test` and `meteor`
3. default app loads fine on `localhost:3000`
4. create a `/private` folder and place a 500 mb text file there
5. `meteor` dies partway without ever loading on `localhost:3000`
6. Removed `/private` folder and re-ran.
7. Works again.

Anyone knows what may be causing this problem?